# PHP Preg_Match_All Returning No Results

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am using [Simple HTML Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) Parser to scrape a script tag from a webpage and then attempting to parse certain data from said tag using preg_match_all(). However, when I print preg_match_all, no results are returned.

Below is the code I'm using:

```
<head>
    <?php
        require_once "toolkit/http.php";
        require_once "toolkit/web_browser.php";
        require_once "toolkit/simple_html_dom.php";
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        $prod_url = 'http://www.domain.com/subpage.html';
        $html = file_get_html($prod_url);
        $script = $html->find('script', 17);
        //echo $script;
        preg_match_all('(?<=\d":)\w++', $script, $matches);
        print_r($matches);

    ?>
</body>
```

I can see that the HTML Simple Dom code is working correctly, as I get the results I expect when echoing the `$script` variable. The results are:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var PRODUCT_JSON = {
    "Def":{
        "default":202705111,
        "Listing:[{
            "label":"Includes",
            "options":[
                {label:"All", id: "884"},
                {label:"None", id: "485"},
            ]
        }],
        "Lookup":{
            "1":202705111,
            "0":202493236
        }
        }
};
</script>
```

So, the issue appears to be with the regex I'm using in  preg_match_all(). The goal of the regex is to return the two numbers, 202705 and 202493, near the end of the script tag. It may have to do with escaping the double quote or parentheses, though I've also tried `preg_match_all('\(?<=\d\":\)\w++', $script, $matches);` with the same result. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Write your regex as `'#(?<=\d":)\w++#'`. `#` are delimiters (which you can change to `/` or `@` or `%` to avoid escaping them).

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the jSON parser (json_decode())? (BTW preg_match_all('/(?:"\d":\s*)\w++/'....) seems to work for me)

Comment: @nhahtdh Thank you! The delimiters are exactly what I needed.

Comment: @symcbean: You would need to extract the text out before you can use a JSON parser. A JS parser is necessary for that.

Comment: @symcbean No reason in particular, I'm just not familiar with the json parser. Are there any particular benefits to using that, considering I now have the above code working as expected?

Comment: @user994585: Less prone to parsing the wrong stuffs, when the structure of the page changes.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks, makes sense. I'll take a look into that.

Comment: @nhahtdh: The DOM Parser does *most* of that

Comment: @symcbean: From how you say it, it really sounds like you have to extract the object in the script with regex

Comment: @nhahtdh: yes, one would still need to extract the object - although the example here its JSON compliant, in the absence of a formal declaration of how the document is structured that's not necessarily the case - however when that breaks, anything else short of a full javascript parser will break. But it would be more robust than trying to parse the script solely with regexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep forgetting about delimiters, you can use [T-Regx](https://github.com/Danon/T-Regx), which automatically adds delimiters.

```
$matches = pattern('(?<=\d":)\w++')->match($script)->all();
```